# Add two-line text to video in ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm trying to write a two-line text to video with ffmpeg. Adding a \n inside the text does not create a new line, and the long text does not automatically split to two lines.
Here's my command:

```
ffmpeg -i Double-onBeat-Bassline.mov -filter:v "drawtext=text='Deep House Pattern #6 -\n Double On-Beat Bassline':bordercolor=black:fontcolor=white:borderw=5:fontsize=100:x=w/2-tw/2:y=h/2-th/2" Double-OnBeat-Bassline-out.mp4
```

Is it possible to insert a new line in the text?

Comment: See "Multiple lines" section of https://stackoverflow.com/a/22719247/

Comment: Thank you @llogan. It helped a lot